# ASP.NET MVC delete method pass an Id / model to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Using Razor pages for my views, I can't find a way to pass an Id / bounded model to my controller.

I have created a delete template view with my model, added a delete action method to my controller, but I can't figure out how to pass any parameters.

```
@model AdventureWorks.Models.HumanResources.Department

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteConfirmed", "Department", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
    <div>
        <h4>Department</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GroupName)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GroupName)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
            </dd>

        </dl>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Department department)
    {
        return ViewDepartments();
    }
```

The Department object that is returned, is a new object with no properties set.

Could you advise me, how to pass at least an Id of the to be deleted object?
I managed to get the model with the form on my create and update method, but I can't figure out, how to do the same on delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the parameters you want to pass in Html.BeginForm.Here is a demo:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteConfirmed", "Department",new { Id=Model.Id}, FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
}
```

result:
[image]
And you don't need to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`,because your form method is post.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayFor will not do the Model binding.
Assuming Id is a key of Department, add

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

inside of Html.BeginForm.

Inside of you delete action use department.Id to find and delete the item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass some value to your controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteConfirmed", "Department", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id) // Use valid expression for id property

    ...
}
```

And change signature of DeleteConfirm method to

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id) // Use valid id property type
{
    // Delete object
}
```

That should do the trick.